# An issue with my display function

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm working on a project for  class that employs a class called employee. Where I'm having an issue is with the display function. Everything displays correctly until the end where it proceeds to output a list of symbols that eventually throwing:

exception is thrown: read access violation.
this was 0xFF4000.

I've narrowed to issue to either the display function or the loop that outputs the display. Any help with this issue would be much appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class Employee {
private:
    int empcode;
    char empname[10];

public:
    void getdata();
    void display();

};

void Employee::getdata() {
    cout << "\nNAME : ";
    cin >> empname;
    cout << "\nCODE : ";
    cin >> empcode;
} 

void Employee::display() {
    cout << endl << setw(20) << empname << setw(10) << empcode << endl;
}

int main()
   {
Employee Emp[6];

    cout << "Enter employee details:\n ";
   for (int i = 0; i<6; i++)
{
    cout << "\nemployee " << i + 1 << endl; 
    Emp[i].getdata();
}
cout << "\nEmployee details are as follows :";
cout << "\n\n" << setw(20) << "NAME" << setw(10) << "CODE";
cout << "\n------------------------------";

for (int i = 0; 1 <= 6; i++)
    Emp[i].display();

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second loop is wrong:

for (int i = 0; `1 <= 6`; i++)

Should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
```

`1 < 6` will loop all the time, but your `i++` will be increasing every iteration, when it gets 6, it tries to access to nonexistent element `Emp[6]`, there are only `Emp[0]...Emp[5]`

Comment: Thank you, I had been staring at the problem for so long I completely missed that I put a 1 where i should be.

Comment: @JohnHoward also don't forget about comparison signs, `i<6` is right, not `i<=6`, because `i<=6` will affect `Emp[6]` at last iteration